# OR condition in MongoDB text search using C#

Tags: c#, mongodb

I am querying mongodb from C# using the .NET Driver for mongodb. 
The following code gives me the restaurant names which contains "Foods" in the name.

```
public void FindResName(string question)
    {
        _client = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");
        _database = _client.GetDatabase("test");
        var collection = _database.GetCollection<BsonDocument>("restaurants");

        collection.Indexes.CreateOne(
          Builders<BsonDocument>.IndexKeys.Text("name"),
          new CreateIndexOptions() { DefaultLanguage = "english", Name = "NameTextIndex" });

        var results = collection.Find(Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Text("Foods"))
        .Project(Builders<BsonDocument>.Projection.MetaTextScore("textScore"))
        .Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.MetaTextScore("textScore"))
        .ToList();

       for(int count=0; count<10; count++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(results[count]["name"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

I want something like this

```
db.restaurants.find( { $text: { $search: "foods cafe mall" } } )
```

This query in mongodb will return the **restaurants that has either foods OR cafe OR mall or combinations of these in their name.** I have no idea how I can do this in C#. **How can I apply the OR condition in C# when querying mongodb?(text search)**

Comment: So `Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Text("foods cafe mall")` didnt work for you ?

Comment: It worked. Solved.